# QueryPath changing iframe tags to self-closing?

Tags: querypath

I'm using QueryPath to wrap a `<div>` around embedded videos on a site that contains a mixture of `<object>` and `<iframe>` embeds.

I tried the following code:

```
    $content = qp($content)
    ->find('object,iframe,a.evdPlayer')
    ->wrap('<div class="splashBack"></div>')
    ->top('body')->children()
    ->html(); // << It's wanting to remove the </iframe> Grrr.
return $content;
```

But it seems to want to change my `<iframe></iframe>` code to `<iframe />`, which is messing things up for some reason. Is there a way to keep it from changing the tags it's wrapping?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

the ->html method does not set the LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG flag when using DOMDocument::saveXML, if you need the closing tags you should use ->xhtml instead which passes this flag. eg

```
    $content = qp($content)
    ->find('object,iframe,a.evdPlayer')
    ->wrap('<div class="splashBack"></div>')
    ->top('body')->children()
    ->xhtml();
    return $content;
```

Comment: upvote + i had success putting some dummy content in the tag itself as a hack

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution that seems to work. It turns out that by inserting some content between the ... querypath recognizes the need for the closing tag and leaves it alone. It's a hack, but it works for now!

```
$content = qp($content)
    ->find('object,iframe,a.evdPlayer')
    ->text('[ video embed ]')
    ->wrap('<div class="splashBack"></div>')
    ->top('body')->children()
    ->html(); // << It's wanting to remove the </iframe>
return $content;
```